# Error: Cannot find module './command' when running istanbul

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

When running mocha with istanbul (`istanbul cover _mocha`) sometimes the message `Error: Cannot find module './command'` and I need to remove the node_modules folder and reinstall in order to make it work again.

So far I could not replicate the exact conditions of this happening, but is usually after after I ran several tests.

Mocha still works, and between my dependencies for testing (mocha,chai and istanbul) command module only appears as direct dependency in istanbul. Currently using `"istanbul": "^0.4.5"` and `node 6.6.0`

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this may be due to your node_modules/.bin/ folder having files instead of the expected symlinks. This can happen by copying your repo to another directory with node_modules already installed. To fix, try this:

```
cd bad_repo_dir
rm -fr node_modules
cd ../good_repo_dir
cp -a node_modules ../bad_repo_dir
cd ../bad_repo_dir
npm test
```

This -a on the copy command tells it to duplicate attributes as well as symlinks, etc. Hope that helps!